# Plurals in RDoc documentation

Tags: ruby, documentation, rdoc

According to the [RDoc documentation](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/), names of classes, source files, and any method names containing an underscore or preceded by a hash character are automatically hyperlinked. But [links to plurals of class names in RDoc](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/10) do not work. Therefore in a sentence like "A Post has many Comments", `Post` is linked, but `Comment` is not. There seems to be a workaround like this

```
A Post has many Comments[class_link:Comment.html].
```

but it is a bit lengthy. Is there any better way to link to plural names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also possible to use..

```
Comments[link:Comment.html]
```

..or, according to the [RDoc documentation](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html)

```
Comments[rdoc-ref:Comment]
```

The general format of RDoc links is `label[url]` or `{label}[url]`, see the [RDoc documentation](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Markup.html). Unfortunately the simple form `Comments[Comment]` does not work, which would be similar to the MediaWiki syntax for internal Links, where one would write `[[Comment|Comments]]`.